# How to run two instances of the same java program in parallel?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a java program which uses `HttpUrlConnection` to make `POST` calls. What I want to do now is to see if there are 2-3 parallel calls making the same changes, then what happens. Is each call able to make the rewuired changes, and if not then which call is given precedence.
To debug for this, I need to run parallel instances of the same java program in eclipse. How can this be done?
I don't want to use threads, a totally independent execution of the same program.

Comment: Just launch the program more than one time ? I don't really see where the problem is exactly.

Comment: Use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to test parallel connections.

Comment: Why must it be "in Eclipse"?  Just run the application multiple times using X command prompts / shells. But that is in no way a guarantee that it is going to happen in parallel, that depends on how many CPUs/cores the computer has available and how the OS chooses to prioritize it all. If you want a guarantee, use X computers rather than X instances of the program.

Answer (score -1):

Compile the source and run the program from command line.

> We want to separate the source from the generated files, so our java
>   source files will be in src folder. All generated files should be
>   under build, and there splitted into several subdirectories for the
>   individual steps: classes for our compiled files and jar for our own
>   JAR-file.
>
> We have to create only the src directory. (Because I am working on
>   Windows, here is the win-syntax - translate to your shell):

```
md src
```

> The following simple Java class just prints a fixed message out to
>   STDOUT, so just write this code into `src\oata\HelloWorld.java`.

```
package oata;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

> Now just try to compile and run that:

```
md build\classes
javac -sourcepath src -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java
java -cp build\classes oata.HelloWorld
```

Read more [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).

You can also build into a `jar` and create a script to multiple execute the program.